# Why did the author use reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Here is a code snippet of Effective C++ Item 50:

```
static const int signature = 0xDEADBEEF;

typedef unsigned char Byte;

// this code has several flaws — see below
void* operator new(std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    using namespace std;
    size_t realSize = size + 2 * sizeof(int); // increase size of request so 2
    // signatures will also fit inside
    void *pMem = malloc(realSize); // call malloc to get the actual
    if (!pMem) throw bad_alloc(); // memory

    // write signature into first and last parts of the memory
    *(static_cast<int*>(pMem)) = signature; 
    *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(static_cast<Byte*>(pMem)+realSize-sizeof(int))) = signature;
    // return a pointer to the memory just past the first signature
    return static_cast<Byte*>(pMem) + sizeof(int);

}
```

Why did the author use `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`? Can I replace all the four casts only with `reinterpret_cast` or `static_cast`?

Comment: Did you note the comment saying that the code is wrong?  Did you read the explanation that follows?  These dereferenced pointer casts need to be replaced with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did the author use `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`?

`static_cast` could convert pointer type to `void*` and convert it back, but it can't convert between pointer to unrelated types. [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) could.

> 5) Any pointer to object of type T1 can be converted to pointer to
>   object of another type cv T2. This is exactly equivalent to
>   `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))` (which implies
>   that if T2's alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's, the
>   value of the pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting
>   pointer back to its original type yields the original value). In any
>   case, the resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed
>   by the type aliasing rules (see below)